# How to configure a smartphone as a Wi-Fi range extender (repeater)?

Tags: wi-fi

My Wi-Fi router's signal is too weak to reach my room (around a corner).  I have an Android smartphone.

What steps would I follow to configure it as a Wi-Fi repeater?

Comment: Phones can not be used a Wifi repeater in original (stock, unrooted, jailed) state. An rooted Android device may be able to do so using the underlaying Linux system and configuring it by hand. Not sure about iPhone.